# How to access window variable in Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is the below code correct ? I want to access the window variable in a javascript object.

```
export const configs={
  //firebase configuration
  apiKey: window._env_.API_KEY,
  projectId: window._env_.PROJECT_ID,
  messagingSenderId: window._env_.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  backendURL: window._env_.BACKEND_URL
}
```

Comment: Where and how you have set these variables? Can you also show that part. Just put `xxxx` in place of actual `API_KEY` value just to be safe.

Comment: Really depends on the context of this code. Syntax-wise it’s at least not invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code is executed in a browser, `window` is available as a global object. However, if this code is executed in a node environment (server side), `window` will be undefined.

Here's one way to handle this if your code will execute both server-side (node environment) and client-side (browser environment):

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  configs = {
    //firebase configuration
    apiKey: window._env_.API_KEY,
    projectId: window._env_.PROJECT_ID,
    messagingSenderId: window._env_.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    backendURL: window._env_.BACKEND_URL
  }
} else {
  // handle server-side logic here
}
```

If there's no need for this to execute in the browser, it would be simplest to just use `process.env` instead of setting these variables on the window. If you do need these variables in both places (and they're coming from `process.env`), this might be another solution:

```js
const env = typeof window === 'undefined' ? process.env : window._env_;

export const configs = {
  //firebase configuration
  apiKey: env.API_KEY,
  projectId: env.PROJECT_ID,
  messagingSenderId: env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  backendURL: env.BACKEND_URL
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new js file, then write as below. File name is appsettings.js

```
window.appSettings = {
    apiKey: '${REACT_API_KEY}',
    projectId: '${REACT_PROJECT_ID}',
    messagingSenderId: '${REACT_SENDER_ID}',
    backendURL: '${REACT_BACKEND_URL}'
};
```

env files

```
REACT_API_KEY=value
REACT_PROJECT_ID=value
REACT_SENDER_ID=value
REACT_BACKEND_URL=value
```

Public/index.html

```
<script src="http://localhost/appsettings.js?v={version}"></script>
    <script>
        window.appSettings.apiKey= '%REACT_API_KEY%';
        window.appSettings.projectId= '%REACT_PROJECT_ID%';
        window.appSettings.messagingSenderId= '%REACT_SENDER_ID%';
        window.appSettings.backendURL= '%REACT_BACKEND_URL%';
    </script>
```

Where you want to use, write this code

```
window.appSettings.apiKey
```

Not need declare another place because it declare index.html